# use third party lib in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i want create an angular directive for persian datepicker, javascript lib that i want to use is http://jspersiandatepicker.codeplex.com/, and my code is :

```
<input type="text" persiandatepicker ng-model="mydate" />{{mydate}}

directive('persiandatepicker', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          if (!ngModel) return;

          ngModel.$render = function () {
              element.bind("click", function () {
              PersianDatePicker.Show(this, ngModel.$viewValue || '');
          });

      };
   }
};
});
```

this code show datepicker when click on input and when select date show in input, but model not bind and not change how can i do binding in this sample??
this link in plunker is my code : http://plnkr.co/edit/AQsvlbdGHCVpjMeCbR3c?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is a good one Available. it's a Persian angularjs calendar:
[Amin Rahimi's angularjs Datepicker](https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker) .

Comment: How can I use it in my project. Actually I added it as a module to my project, but I don't know whether it is directive or not and also how to put it in my html code

Answer (score 3):

You need to let angular know that the value has changed.  It looks like the datepicker calls _textBox.onchange(); when it is finished updating the textbox so you can hook into that event.  You will need to wrap your code in

```
 element.bind("onchange", function () {
     scope.$apply(function() {
         //Code to update model goes here.
         //Basically you will need to copy the textbox's contents to the model,
         // you may wish to convert to a date object as well
     }
 }
```

The [angularui datepicker](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date/blob/master/src/date.js) source code is only 120 lines long and could be a great resource if you are looking for an example on creating a datepicker directive.

Comment: i test your code bute onchange in directive not raise when input text change, this link in plunker is my code <http://plnkr.co/edit/AQsvlbdGHCVpjMeCbR3c?p=preview>

Comment: I edited your plunker, I had to modify the source of the datepicker, so be sure to take a look at that file as well.

http://plnkr.co/edit/caVUpBbtMAGEEuqzRADX?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this version of angular-ui bootstrap that has persian calendar: [persian angular bootstrap](https://github.com/rkeshmir/persian-angular-ui-bootstrap)